# How to copy a folder from a dockerfile's parent into workdir

Tags: docker

So I have a tree that looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── dataloader
│   ├── Dockerfile
...
│   ├── log.py
│   ├── logo.py
│   ├── processors
...
│   └── tests
├── datastore
│   ├── datastore.py
```

and the Dockerfile inside the dataloader application looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /var/dsys-2uid-dataloader

  COPY assertions/ ./assertions/
  COPY events/ ./events/
  COPY processors/ ./processors/
  COPY requirements.txt ./
<*>COPY datastore/ ./datastore/
  COPY *.py ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "dataloader.py"]
```

the line with the asterisk doesn't work since the datastore folder is in the parent of the `Dockerfile`. What can be done? I need this Dockerfile to be correct because it's going to be used as the image in the kubernetes deployment.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a file outside of your build context, but you can "trick" docker to be in a different build context.

Just run `docker build -t foo -f dataloader/Dockerfile .` from the root directory (where you have the README and the dirs)

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── wii
└── foo
    └── Dockerfile

2 directories, 2 files

$ cat foo/Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
COPY bar/wii .

$ docker build -t test -f foo/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> cf0f3ca922e0
Step 2/2 : COPY bar/wii .
 ---> c3ff3f652b4d
Successfully built c3ff3f652b4d
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Comment: I'd also add the caution that everything in the Docker context is sent to the daemon when you build, so if you do this and you have lots of data in one of the sibling directories (at the same level as `foo` and `bar` in your example), e.g. build caches etc, you will find the build process very slow.  In this case, consider using a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file.